# Google Maps Drawing API: Invalid value for property <map>: [object Object]

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps

I'm trying to integrate the Google Maps Drawing Manager into my Map, but this seamingly easy step has been puzzling me for the last hour. Somehow the DrawingManager doesn't accept my map object in the setMap() method or the map: option setting.

[Here is a demo website](http://labs.shifthappens.nl/vagabond/PILOT/) where you can see the error being generated. Open up the console window, hover over "Where should Hollie go next?" and then click on that same text (yes UI design is next step :P) to trigger the error.

I can see that the manager doesn't recognize my map as being of the right type, but that's weird: everywhere else I can perfectly refer to the map object. I store the map object in document.map, but I also tried assigning it to a normal var "map_" outside the functions. Also no effect. I even tried marker.getMap() to see if that worked, but the same error pops up.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I had the same problem, hope this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9786272/loading-multiple-maps-libraries-with-javascript

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same error as title recently. But in my case, I used the newer version of google maps API, which is conflict with other googlemap-related API.

To include older version of Google Maps API, just add **v** to your query string, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.5&libraries=geometry&sensor=true_or_false"></script>
```

Don't know if it's work for you...