# Loading multiple maps libraries with javascript

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to load both the maps library and the places library with javascript so I can embed a map into my page, use google.maps.geometry.spherical functions and make places search requests but I'm having trouble loading all 3 libraries.
At the moment I am importing:

```
<script type="text/javascript"src="http://maps.google.com/maps?key=mykey"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
```

But I get the errors:

```
syntax error
[Break On This Error]   

...gs4d .gbmac,.gbes#gbg4 #gbgs4d .gbmac{margin:34px 0 0}.gbemi#gb #gbgs4d .gbmac,....

maps?k...hrkDAmw (line 1)

GClientGeocoder is not defined
[Break On This Error]   

var geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();
```

Where am I going wrong?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You're not using v2 code with the v3 api are you?  it would help if you posted the code that causes the error.

Answer (score 68):

The first script doesn't point to a javascript, this will try to load the [maps-homepage](http://maps.google.com/maps?key=AIzaSyCoiF1SlcuQPqoRdbP58ZCi3YrPx412345) as a script(of course this will fail).

There is no need to include multiple scripts, simply use:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry,places&sensor=false">
```

This will load the maps-API(V3) and includes the places+geometry-libraries

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/libraries?hl=en

However, as  Colin said, this looks like V2-code.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add comma between different libraries, instead of adding new script.

e.g

```
<script type="text/javascript"src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=drawing,places&sensor=false">
```

you can see the code having comma between 'drawing' and 'places' library.

Answer (score -2):

You can use it in this way

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_KEY&libraries=places"></script>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack OverflowWhen giving an answer you should try and explain it as well as post the code. And just so you know you can format your code so using the tool bar.